# Microsoft report viewer object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

I am developing a c# windows form application on Microsoft Visual studio 2013 Express for windows desktop also i am using SQL server 2012 express with Advanced features included reporting services. and my operating system is Windows 8.1 64bit. (I am also trying this on Win 7 64bit Pro) So...

SQL server with reporting services is installed, .Net Framework 4.5.1 is installed. and microsoft report viewer 2012 runtime is installed on my computer.

My problem is however those components are already installed on my computer, I can not see a seperate tab named as reporting and microsoft report viewer object in Visual Studio toolbox. I have to add report viewer control/object from choose item context menu of toolbox window. Even i add this control/object from choose items window it is not working on my windows form. I mean i can choose it but i can not drag and drop it on the form. Whenever i drag and drop reportviewer object on the form, object appears under my windows form but there is no designable object appears on the windows form as you can see in the image. So can someone please help me? why cant i add this **reportviewer** object on my form properly and why can't I design it?

You can see the image by opening the following link.
http://i39.tinypic.com/2yjolzs.png

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely that the ReportViewer on your toolbox is not version 11.0 which would be the reason why it is not working as expected.

Follow these steps to get the ReportViewer control to work in VS 2013 Express:

1. Remove the current ReportViewer from the toolbox. Right click in toolbox window >> Choose Items >> deselect ReportViewer under .NET framework Components.
2. Remove the ReportViewer object that appears under the form and remove references for ReportViewer under Solution Explorer. These references would be Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common & Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.
3. If Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime is already installed, then you should have the ReportViewer version 11.0 available to be added to VS. To check, right click in toolbox window >> Choose Items >> under .NET framework Components select Browse, browse to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms. Open folder 11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91 and select Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.DLL. This will add ReportViewer version 11.0 into the list of .NET framework Components from where you then add to your toolbox.

Note: If you don't find folder 11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91, that means Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime is not installed. To install the 2012 Runtime download from this link [Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/downl....aspx?id=35747)

Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: I don't know if this worked for the other guy but it worked for me!!