# Reportviewer not dragging to form

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

After much searching and no clear answers, I an baffled by the following:

I an using Visual Studio Community 2013 and VB.NET.

The reportviewer control does not drag onto a blank form. It only shows as Reportviewer1 at the bottom of the form design screen.

What am I missing ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: another stack users had what appears to be the same problem - Rather than copy and paste the info, I'll link to it as the page isn't likely to disappear anytime soon. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094181/microsoft-report-viewer-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094181/microsoft-report-viewer-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft report viewer object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094181/microsoft-report-viewer-object)

Comment: Thank you I tried that and it works! But... only if I start a new project. On an exiting project I am having problems - which of course I fail to resolve. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Download and install MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME

using this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35747

Answer (score 0):

delete that version then install this version:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio
and go to the nudget install version 14